# How to make a return in the form of a whole message in the __str__ model function in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I just would like getting a next str in my html: made by John Kennedy.

But now I have the next str: made by ('John', 'Kennedy')

There is the cod from model:

```
class Teams(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('First name', max_length=15, default='Name')
    second_name = models.CharField('Second name', max_length=30, default='Family' )
    ---...----
     def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.first_name, self.second_name}'

class Portfolio (models.Model):
     ---...----
     name = models.ForeignKey (Teams, related_name='maked', on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True)
     ---...----
```

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.second_name}'
```